# When using google cloud messaging for chrome, is there any limit to messages pushed at 1 request?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, push, google-cloud-messaging

The limitation of sending request is 10,000/day,
but how many messages can we push at 1 request?

When using GCM, there is an limitation of pushing to 1000 devices at 1 request.
Is it the same for GCM for chrome as it is for GCM?

Answer (score 1):

Well Push Notification for chrome Free quota is 10,000 requests/day. Till it's does't support payload(data) delivery. So the limit means you can only send 10,000 push notifications in a day. whether it could be multi cast or single.

Answer (score 0):

When writing the code for [Push Messaging for Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web?hl=en), You need to initialize a variable of Boolean type to true or false.

```
var isPushEnabled;
```

If you implement Push notification in your web app whenever this Boolean will be set to ***true*** the web app will receive the push notification. It is not device dependent like GCM. It will send the push notification to all the users who have enabled the Push Notification on your website.

Please check the `listener` code on the link above.